# How to disable iOS Mail App text enlargement

Tags: ios, css, email, html-email, email-client

I wanted to use an ascii art for my email signature and it works pretty fine in Gmail, Polymail, and a few other clients. The only exception is the iOS Mail App that will enlarge my ascii code and therefore destroying the image. How can I prevent the Mail App from doing so?

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

doesn't seem to work any more (neither does `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`) as stated here: [How to avoid iOS automatic font size adjustment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210788/how-to-avoid-ios-automatic-font-size-adjustment)

The signature I am trying to get to show properly in iOS Mail app:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0; max-width: 400px; font-size: 4px; font-family: monospace; line-height: 3px; color: #000000; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; text-size-adjust: 100%;"> 
      ++++++=====================================~~~~~~~~~===================================+++++++++++++<br/>+++++================================~~=~=~~~~~~~~~~~~~================================+++++++++++++<br/>++++==============================~~~=~~~~=~~~~~~~=~~~~~~~=============================+++++++++++++<br/>++++===========================~OOOOOOOOOOOOO8OOOOOOOOOOOOO88888O8OO====================++++++++++++<br/>+++=========================~DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDNNNDNNDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDM8==================+++++++++++<br/>+==========================ODDDDDDDNNNNNNNNNNNDDDDNDDNNNNNNNNDNDNDDDDDDND==================+++++++++<br/>+========================ZNDDDDNNND88DDDDNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDDDDDDDNNNDDDDNDD==============+=+++++++++<br/>+===========$OZZO8====~DNNNDDDNNNNOOO8888DNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDDDDDDDDNNNDDDNDNZ+=====OOZOOO===+++++++++<br/>===========ZII$Z8DN===ONDD8DDNNNNNN88888DNDNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDDDNNNNNNNNNNNDNNNNM8===NDZ$IIOO==+++++++++<br/>============~DD8OD==ON8OZZZZOOZMZ8MNNNNNNNDDDD88888888NMNM8DDDDNDDNNNNNMNDD8DDZ~+NODDDN=====++++++++<br/>===============7=ZZZZZOZOOOOOOOOOOOOO8D8DD88DDDDDDDDDDDDDD88DD8OO888OOOOOOOOOZOOOOZO~=======++++++++<br/>==============ZZ:ZZZZZZOOZOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO888888888O888888888OOOOOOOOOOOOZZOO8========++++++<br/>==============Z$~~$I7ZZZZZOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO8888888888O888888OO8OOOOZOOZZ78ZZOOO==========++++<br/>=============$$$7~$~DNNND7ZZZOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO888888OOOOOOOO8OOOOOOOO88NNNNN.ZZOOO==========++++<br/>=============Z$777?O$~?.D,ZNNOOOOOOZOOOOOOOOOOOOOO88OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONNO.N.$I=8ZZZOO============++<br/>============~Z$77II$NI?Z.88ZZZOOOO$77$ZZOOOOOOOOO8OOOO8OOOOOOOZ$7ZOOOOOOZON.8~DM$$ZZO8I=============<br/>===========~~OO$$7$777Z$?ZZZZZOOOOZZZZZZZZZOZOOOZO$8OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOZZZZZ7OZ$$$ZZO8DI=============<br/>===========~~7OOZOZ?,7$$$$$$ZZZOOOZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ8OOOOOOOOOOOOZZZOOOZZZZZ$$77:?O8888$=~~~==========<br/>=======~~~~~~DOZZZZ$Z88OOO$=$$$OO$Z$ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZOOOOOOOOOOZZZZZZOOOZ$7+O88DDDZOO8888~~~~~~~~~=====<br/>=====~=~~~~~~DOOZZZZZMMNMO$88888DDDOOOOOOOOOOO8OOOO88888888O8OOOODDDD8DD8Z8MNMNDOO8888~~~~~~~~=~====<br/>====~~~~~~~~~8OOZZZDOMMMNMNMMMNMMM8OOOOOO8OO88888888888888888888ODMNMNNMMNDMMMMDNOO888+~~~~~~~~~~~~~<br/>=~~~~~~~~~~~~D8OOZNDMMMMNNMMDNMMMMNO88888888888888DD8888888888888NMMNMMNDNNNMMMNNDO888+~~~~~~~~~~~~~<br/>~~~~~~~~~~~~~D8OOZDDMMMMNMMNDMNMNDD$$888888888888DDDDDDD8888DDDIZNNNMNNNMNNMMMMMNDO888+~~~~~~~~~~~~~<br/>~::::::::~~~~D88OZDNMMMNNMNNDNNNO$$7NMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM8?ZZZNMNDDNDNMMMMN8O888+~~~~~~~~~~~~~<br/>::::::::::~~~N8888O+DZOOZOOOO8D8$$ONMMMNNNMNNNMMNNNMMNMNNMNNNMMMDI$Z8D888OOOOOO8$O888N?+=~~~~:::::::<br/>:::::::::~~=+DNN8888O??77$$$$$$$$8NNDD8OZ$$$77$$ZOOZZZZZOO88DDNNNMO$ZZZZ$$$7I+OO888DNNI?+=~~::::::,,<br/>,,,,::::~~=+I7MMMMMMMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMMMMMMMNNNZ$I?+=~~:::::,<br/>:::~~~=+?7$OOOMNNMNMMMMNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNMMMMMMMM88OOOZ$I?+=~~::<br/>,,,,,:::~~==+?I$Z8DDDDDDDDNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNDDDDD8O$I?+==~~:::,,,,,,,<br/>,,,,,,.............,......,...........,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,...............................,,,,,,,,,,,,,<br/>,,,,,,,,......................................................................,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<br/>,,,,,,,,,..,,,,,,....................................................,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,<br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you provide some code so we can duplicate your issue

Comment: @Gortonington I added a snippet

Comment: I ran your snippet through Email On Acid to check display on iOS and the text stayed the declared size with the current code. Sorry, wish I could be more help...

Comment: Yes, I guess it's because these simulators use Webkit engine to emulate the Webview for Emails, which actually works (probably the reason why Polymail and other iOS email clients also show up properly). But I suspect that Mail App doesn'tuse the webkit webview and so resizes the text. You gotta actually send yoursef that sniopet and open on Mail App to see it, but I also have no clue how you would debug that. Apple things as usually I guess :-/

Comment: Services like Email on Acid and Litmus do not use emulators, they use real devices / browsers with real email clients, take a snapshot, and save a PNG. However their installable clients aren't always up to date.

Comment: I see. I didn't have a look on that service and was just assuming how it would work, guess next time I better have :€ :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none|100%` only works reliably with **font sizes 14px and above**. I'm not suggesting you change the design of the ascii art, but might be worth testing a larger font-size just to see if you can successfully negate iOS Mail's text-resizing.