# Font size increases when clicking on an anchor/link(in a specific page) in iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile-safari

This problem is occuring in iphones only. I checked it in an iphone 5(landscape mode) and iphone 4s(landscape mode).

Here's a [link](https://i.imgur.com/HXsCjzl.gifv) to the video

I tried specifying the font size but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like iphones auto resize the text and to avoid that I used this:

```
body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
or
body {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none; } /* works perfectly in landscape mode */
```

For future users: If you're having issues similar to this in firefox, you can try to fix it with this.

`body { moz-text-size-adjust:100%; }`

---

So after a couple of hours of searching SO I found out that mobile Safari does try to adapt content so that it's readable on screen by default - it has different default styles to other browsers.

I don't know the exact rules - but when it comes to font sizes, it seems to work like this:

- **Text inside a paragraph, list item, or other 'text' element:** Apply the author's style without adapting.
- **Text inside a DIV or other non-specific element:** Treat as 'plain text' and 'adapt' the size according to Mobile Safari's rules.

So - the short answer is, wrap your text in a paragraph, and apply the font-size rule to that.

[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210788/how-to-avoid-ios-automatic-font-size-adjustment)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply fix with this `meta` tag , try to add this to your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: I already tried this but it didn't change a thing. It's just happening in iphones only.

Comment: I just updated with the link of the page where problem is occurring if you want to take a look.